# Background color in radar figure

Tags: microsoft-excel, colors

Consider the following radar figure:

[image]

I want the three background color (green, yellow and blue), but I want them another place.

Instead I want the green one from the middle point between "Jun" and "Jan" to the middle point between "Feb" and "Mar". The yellow one from the middle point between "Feb" and "Mar" to the middle point between "Apr" and "May". And the blue for the rest.

So I want to start the color between the axis labels instead of on the axis labels.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add rows between each row of data, like so:

[image]

[image]

If you really want the hexagonal shape, you can use the following:
[image]

[image]

Note, in both cases, you will want to make sure "Connect data points with line" is selected under Select Data Source --> Hidden and Empty Cell Settings

[image]